# How to use the best parameter as parameter of a classifier in GridSearchCV?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, grid-search

I have a function called `svc_param_selection(X, y, n)` which returns `best_param_`.
Now I want to use the best_params returned as the parameter of a classifier like:
 .

```
parameters = svc_param_selection(X, y, 2)

from sklearn.model_selection import ParameterGrid

from sklearn.svm import SVC

param_grid = ParameterGrid(parameters)

for params in param_grid:
    svc_clf = SVC(**params)
    print (svc_clf)

classifier2=SVC(**svc_clf)
```

It seems parameters is not a grid here..

Comment: Use [GridSearchCV](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html) that you mentioned in the title of your question ! Then you don't even need to create a custom function `svc_param_selection(X, y, n)` nor cycling through the parameters! That what Scikit-learn is built for!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use GridSearchCV to do this. There is a example here:

```
# Applying GridSearch to find best parameters
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
parameters = [{ 'criterion' : ['gini'], 'splitter':['best','random'], 'min_samples_split':[0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5], 
           'min_samples_leaf': [1,2,3,4,5]},
          {'criterion' : ['entropy'], 'splitter':['best','random'], 'min_samples_split':[0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5],
           'min_samples_leaf': [1,2,3,4,5]} ]
gridsearch = GridSearchCV(estimator = classifier, param_grid = parameters,refit= False, scoring='accuracy', cv=10)
gridsearch = gridsearch.fit(x,y)
optimal_accuracy = gridsearch.best_score_
optimal_parameters = gridsearch.best_params_
```

But for `param_grid` of `GridSearchCV`, you should pass a dictionary of parameter name and value for you classifier. For example a classifier like this:

```
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
classifier = DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state=0, presort=True, 
                                    criterion='entropy')
classifier = classifier.fit(x_train,y_train)
```

Then after finding best parameters by `GridSearchCV` you apply them on you model.

Comment: How exactly do I apply them? Is there an elegant way to pass the parameters?

Answer (score 0):

@Ben At the start of gridsearch, you either specify the classifier outside the param_grid (if you have only one classification method to check) or inside the param_grid. I have made a check for the 'inside' case only.

First, I set the 'classifier' key in the param_grid. That is the key which you need to ask for in the end.

```
param_grid = [
    {'classifier' : [LogisticRegression()],
    ...
    },
    {'classifier' : [RandomForestClassifier()],
    }
]
```

As an example, the result of `gridsearch.best_params_` is:

```
{'classifier': RandomForestClassifier(criterion='entropy', max_depth=2, n_estimators=2),
 'classifier__criterion': 'entropy',
 'classifier__max_depth': 2,
 'classifier__min_samples_leaf': 1,
 'classifier__n_estimators': 2}
```

Then ask this dictionary `gridsearch.best_params_` for the key that you called the `'classifier'`.

clfBest = clfGridSearchBest.best_params_['classifier']

clfBest:
`RandomForestClassifier(criterion='entropy', max_depth=2, n_estimators=2)`

Now just fit clfBest.